# How to insert multiple pivot tables into one worksheet of a workbook using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need assistance with combining all my different pivot analysis into a sheet for single view using pandas,I am not consolidating the data, I only want to have all the pivot tables in different cell of the same sheet.

my script output shown below

```
myexcel=pd.ExcelWriter(path)
pivot1.to_excel(myexcel,sheet_name='sheet1')                
pivot2.to_excel(myexcel,sheet_name='sheet2')    
pivot3.to_excel(myexcel,sheet_name='sheet3')
myexcel.save()
```

I wish to have all the sheets in one sheet

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is rather unorthodox, but it's technically possible using the `startrow` and/or `startcol` variables.

Your first call to the function `to_excel` will write to `sheet1 (0,0)`. If you want to display the second table below that, you can use the `startrow` to increment the starting position.

```py
myexcel = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
spacing = 5 # arbitrary number of rows to put between pivots

pivot1.to_excel(myexcel,sheet_name='sheet1')

offset1 = pivot1.count() + spacing
pivot2.to_excel(myexcel,sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=offset1)

offset2 = offset1 + pivot2.count() + spacing
pivot3.to_excel(myexcel,sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=offset2)
myexcel.save()
```